# What is the big idea behind the AOP implementation

Tags: java, design-patterns, jakarta-ee, aop, aspectj

I wanted to make it clear for me.

I read about AOP concept and I understood that it's a great way to share cross cutting services. (logging, security, transaction...)

But I would like to say/ask something about this idea and it's implementation.

I read there are some ways like AspectJ, JBOSS AOP in order to assimilation AOP to my business logic.

but wasnt it here already long time ago?

let's say for example I want to share a logging or security implementation amongs my components(Java beans, EJB'S, whatsoever.. )

Why couldn't I make a Singleton bean making sure it will has only one instance and as soon as any component will need it's logging/security service it would look-up and use it's service.

Why would I need to understand and have all those "Big" implementations such as aspectj or jboss AOP? What do I miss here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The idea of AOP is to keep common logic in one place (which your singleton solution solves as well) **and** being "invisible" (transparent). With AOP your logging code isn't even part of the business logic, it is "injected" behind the scenes.

Also it is more dynamic - you don't need to call your singleton service every time you need logging. Just configure a pointcut once (like: "*all setters in this package*") and logging will be applied for all existing and new code.

Moreover AOP is much, much more flexible and powerful. You can ask the AOP implementation: "please start a transaction every time I call a method beginning with "`save*`" and taking one argument" or "if method returning `Customer` throws an exception subclassing from `IllegalAgumentException`, call that method again".

AOP is much more than just grouping common logic.

Comment: What if I create parent class and extend have my classes extend from it. I could put all my "perment" logic in that parent class. when a class will extend it, it will be able to enjoy all loggig/secutiry... methods which I would have declared before. I also can create additional methods "create"/"destroy" for perment loggig and such..

Comment: @rayman: but you still need to **call** these methods explicitly (see great code sample *JB Nizet*). AOP will do it for you once instructed, also for the code you haven't written yet! This also means that new programmers will enjoy logging/security features without even knowing about them. Not to mention you are not cluttering your code with base classes/helper methods

Comment: Mybe you could check out my last comment to JB.

Answer (score 6):

You have not understood what AOP is all about. The idea of AOP is to be able to write

```
public void foo() {
    // some business code
}
```

instead of writing

```
public void foo() {
    LogManager.getInstance().log("entering foo...");
    SecurityManager.getInstance().checkUserInRole("fooer");
    TransactionManager.getInstance().startTransaction();
    try {
        // some business code
        TransactionManager.getInstance().commit();
    }
    catch(RuntimeException e) {
        TransactionManager.getInstance().rollback();
        throw e;
    }
    LogManager.getInstance().log("leaving foo...");
}
```

All the cross-cutting concerns (logging, security, transaction management) are outside of the business code, instead of being mixed with the business code, and repeated ad nauseam.

Comment: But you still need to tell the AOP logic when/where you want to use those services.. how it will know that I want to log entry/exit of a method? or if I just want to log.debug something in the middle of my method.. some1 need to tell it to do it. it cant read my mind..

Comment: This is typically done declaratively, in a configuration file or using Java annotations. For example, Spring allows marking a method with `@Transactional`. It also allows configuring an AOP interceptor to make all methods of all beans whose class name ends with `ServiceImpl` transactional (this is just an example). If you need to log something in the middle of your method, then AOP won't help you.

Comment: So let's I will use it for logging/security only.. isnt it a bit overkill just for that? are there more solutions I could use AOP for beside the 3 you mention before?

Comment: @rayman: from the top of my head: transactions, security, logging, performance monitoring, profiling, error handling, synchronization, throttling (APIs) - and probably many others. And yes, using AspectJ only for logging *might* be an overkill

Comment: So honestly if I use EJB'S most of those things already built-in aspect arnt they?

Comment: Yes. EJB uses AOP to implement declarative transactions, declarative security, etc. You get it out of the box.

Comment: Mybe I need to read more how AOP solves cross cutting issues. since i am programming under application servers and most of service which I know of(transaction management, security etc..) being shipped out of the box already.